# Clear textboxes that have equations behind them

Tags: vba, ms-access, textbox

I have constructed a Form in access with two textboxes (Total Hours and Part Removal) that have equations behind them. I now have coded a command to send an email at the click of a command button. Also, I have the code to clear the other textboxes on the form after the email has been sent. Is there a way to clear a textbox that has an equation behind it and have it be able to be used again when the user send the email? Right now when the email is sent the equation textboxes pop up with #### inside.

Thanks in advance :)

```
On Error GoTo errhandle
Me.Filter = "CurrentDate= #" & Format(Me!CurrentDate, "yyyy\-mm\-dd") & "# and DiscoverTime= '" & Me!DiscoverTime & "' and TailNumber= '" & Me!TailNumber & "' and FleetID= '" & Me!FleetID & "'"
Me.FilterOn = True
DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, "email", "", "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"

If [txtpart1hrs] = "" Or [txtpart2hrs] = "" Or [txtpart3hrs] = "" Then
 txtPartRemoval = ""
Else
txtPartRemoval = "=CDbl(Nz([txtpart1hrs],0))+CDbl(Nz([txtpart2hrs],0))+CDbl(Nz([txtpart3hrs],0))"
End If


Me.CurrentDate = vbNullString
Me.DiscoverTime = vbNullString
Me.TailNumber = vbNullString
Me.FleetID = vbNullString
Me.ETIC = vbNullString
Me.NonRteWorkCard = vbNullString
Me.txtWorkOrder = vbNullString
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by equation? Can you show it?

Comment: Behind Part Removal is the addition of 3 other textboxes on the form: =CDbl(Nz([txtpart1hrs],0))+CDbl(Nz([txtpart2hrs],0))+CDbl(Nz([txtpart3hrs],0))

Comment: Total Hours is similar but has more textboxes added together. I was thinking maybe me.totalhours = 0

Comment: So when the textboxes get cleared the formula just shows up ####?

Comment: Try my answer then. You will need to change the variables names as I cannot see all your code to do it

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like if the textboxes are clear do make the formula something else.

```
if [txtPart1Hrs] = "" or [txtPart2Hrs] = "" or [txtPart3hrs] = "" then 
     formulaBox = ""
else
    formulaBox = "=CDbl(Nz([txtpart1hrs],0))+CDbl(Nz([txtpart2hrs],0))+CDbl(Nz([txtpart3hrs],0))"
end if
```

Just replace formulabox with what ever you have set for the text box that contains the formula

EDIT Updated code

Change

```
txtPartRemoval = "=CDbl(Nz([txtpart1hrs],0))+CDbl(Nz([txtpart2hrs],0))+CDbl(Nz([txtpart3hrs],0))"
```

to

```
txtPartRemoval.Value = CDbl(Nz([txtpart1hrs], 0)) + CDbl(Nz([txtpart2hrs], 0)) + CDbl(Nz([txtpart3hrs], 0))
```

try changing

```
txtPartRemoval.Value = CDbl(Nz([txtpart1hrs], 0)) + CDbl(Nz([txtpart2hrs], 0)) + CDbl(Nz([txtpart3hrs], 0))
```

to

```
txtPartRemoval.Value = CDbl([txtpart1hrs].value) + CDbl([txtpart2hrs].value) + CDbl([txtpart3hrs].value)
```

As it will not run at all if one of the boxes is empty anyway due to the check to see if it = "".

Comment: If you could also give me your entire code for this I will look into it

Comment: Ok awesome Ill add what I have but its quite lengthy because I have the code under the command button that adds the record to the table. Ill try to cut it down to just the important parts. Thanks :)

Comment: My error handle keeps popping up for some reason, but it still sends the email and Ive provided a picture of what shows up in the boxes.

Comment: Unfortunatly I cannot see the picture as I am at work and it is blocked. However if the email still gets send and the errHandle always appears do you have an exit function/sub just before the errHandle code is?

Comment: Yes I do for the code if the email is sent and if it is not sent

Comment: Im getting an Run-time error. It says "You cant assign a vlue to this object" for the else portion of the code you suggested.

Comment: Try chaning txtPartRemoval to txtPartRemove.value. I am trying to recreate it and get the error now

Comment: Hmm not sure then to be honest. I thought I had replicated it and managed to fix it with that last bit of code. I had it set to when ever I click it will check to see if the txtPartHrs = "". If they are not "" then puts the formula in and spits out the result. I will keep looking though

Comment: Would it be possible if you uploaded your workbook. Take out any important information and data and then I can try and see why it is happening. As I cannot see why it is working for me when I tried to replicate it, I must of clearly not replicated it enough. So post all your code to so I can look through it

Comment: Could I just email it to you?

Comment: Wouldnt be able to open it from email as at work. Maybe put all your code in paste bin and post the link?

Comment: I cant get on paste bin its blocked at my job.